# Problem with installation of Multiwell Software package and open mpi

Tags: software, high-performance-computing, software-assistance, apple-operating-system

I'm trying to install Multiwell including Thermo. The [manual](https://multiwell.engin.umich.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/569/2022/05/MultiWell-User-Manual-2022.pdf) says under 1.4. that I have to install openmpi before. So I followed the instructions from the multiwell manual but get an error at 8.) "make all install".

This is my error:

```
/Users/andrea/Downloads/openmpi-4.0.7/opal/mca/pmix/pmix3x/pmix/src/atomics/sys/gcc_builtin/atomic.h:197:12: error: address argument to atomic operation must be a pointer to integer or pointer ('pmix_atomic_int128_t *' (aka '_Atomic(pmix_int128_t) *') invalid)
    return __atomic_compare_exchange_n (addr, oldval, newval, false,
           ^                            ~~~~
```

The manual says that my version of Multiwell can used on Linux and Mac. Maybe the problem is I got a MacBook Pro with M1 Chip? I had no problem installing Multiwell on my old MacBook Air with Intel Chip.

But the error looks to me like there is something wrong with mpi? I tried to go on with Multiwell Installation but it doesn't work, like I expected.

Can some one give me a tip how to work around?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but can you let us know if you figured this out over the last 6+ months? Are you still actively needing an answer to this? Please update us!